# How to run test on flutter app using appium

Tags: flutter, appium, flutter-test

Background: we are running our tests in ruby language using appium tool to test Native apps but now we are trying to see if we can move to Flutter and still use appium tool to test flutter apps.

I installed **npm i -g appium-flutter-driver** , I have **appium 1.19.1** version and when i call
and in capabilities i have the following:

```
retryBackoffTime = 50
maxRetryCount = 1
platformName = "android"
automationName = "flutter"
ensureWebviewsHavePages = true
newCommandTimeout = 60000
language = "en"
locale = "en"
deviceName = "Nexus"
app = "app-debug.apk"
fullReset = false
clearSystemFiles = true
waitForQuiescence = false
preventWDAAttachments = true
```

And **gem file** i have these:

```
gem 'pry',                '~> 0.11.3'
gem 'appium_lib', '~> 11.2'
gem 'rest-client',        '~> 1.6.7'
gem 'rspec',              '~> 2.14.1'
gem 'cucumber',           '~> 1.3.15'
gem 'rspec-expectations', '~> 2.14.5'
gem 'spec',               '~> 5.3.4'
gem 'sauce_whisk',        '~> 0.0.13'
gem 'test-unit',          '~> 2.5.5' 
gem 'appium_flutter_finder', '~> 0.2.0'
gem 'appium_lib_core', '~> 4.0'
gem 'selenium-webdriver', '~> 3.142', '>= 3.142.7'
gem 'minitest', '~> 5.0'
```

And added the libraries:
require 'appium_lib_core'
require 'appium_flutter_finder'
require 'minitest/autorun'

but i am when i try start the driver, it launches the app but when i try to run any methods such as `find_elements(:id, "id")` it doesn't recognize it i get this error:

**undefined method `find_elements' for nil:NilClass**
source 'https://www.rubygems.org'

And this is appium log

```
[MJSONWP (b0d5c72a)] Calling AppiumDriver.findElement() with args: ["id","id","b0d5c72a-6421-491a-a97e-2f460e645f98"]
[FlutterDriver] Executing Flutter driver command 'findElement'
[BaseDriver] Valid locator strategies for this request: key, css selector
[MJSONWP (b0d5c72a)] Encountered internal error running command: InvalidSelectorError: Locator Strategy 'id' is not supported for this session
[MJSONWP (b0d5c72a)]     at FlutterDriver.validateLocatorStrategy (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-flutter-driver/node_modules/appium-base-driver/lib/basedriver/driver.js:388:13)
```

My guess is my driver has issue but not sure why and how i can setup the driver correctly.
Any help would be greatly appreciated